# Глагол-связка и зависимые слова

Tags: синтаксис

Меня заинтересовал следующий вопрос: может ли глагол-связка иметь зависимые слова? К примеру, имеется такое предложение: "«Террор» – это обязательно политика устрашения и применение насилия в отношении политических противников". Правильно ли я понимаю, что слово "обязательно" здесь зависит от нулевой связки?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Террор» – это обязательно (= в обязательном порядке) политика устрашения и применение насилия в отношении политических противников.***

Наречие ***обязательно*** (= в обязательном порядке) относится не к пропущенной связке, а  **к именной часть сказуемого.**

Оно является **несогласованным определением** к существительным *политика и применение*.

Comment: Спасибо. Но вы не ответили на главный вопрос: может ли связка (в том числе и полузнаменательная) иметь зависимые слова? Возможны ли такие случаи в теории?

Comment: В теории такие случаи не зафиксированы.  По определению глагол-связка преимущественно служит для выражения грамматических значений сказуемого, а также для различных модальных или фазовых значений. Все эти значения выражает сам глагол-связка,  зависимых слов он не имеет.